# in a M/M/1/K Queue, the ratio of losses when the incoming rate is combination of two rates

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Generally, In a M/M/1/K system, the incoming rate is $\lambda$, effective incoming rate $\lambda_e$ is equal to $\lambda(1-P_k)$, where $P_k$ is the probability that queue waiting space is full. This is also the outgoing rate.

My question is, if the incoming rate is a combination of two rates, i.e. $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$, then can I assume that both the rates will drop some incomings(due to only K space being available) *at the same ratio*?

I.e. can I assume that outgoing rate in this case is $\lambda_1(1-P_k) + \lambda_2(1-P_k)$ and both the incoming rates have lost jobs in equal proportion?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the incoming rate is a combination of two rates"? The superposition of Poisson processes is again a Poisson process, so the natural interpretation is no different from the original problem.

Comment: The output would be the combined effective rate, but will the loss be of same proportion? As An Example, if mean rate for flow1 is 10 jobs/second, and for flow 2 its 20 jobs/second, so combined incoming rate is 30 jobs/s, and lets say the drop probability is 20%, so for 30 packets, 6 will be dropped.

Question is, Can I assume that, in long run,  2 job/s will be dropped from 1st flow and 4 jobs/s will be dropped from the second flow? or the drop values might be different?

Comment: The superposition of two Poisson processes with rates $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$. So unless we have reason to distinguish arrivals from the two processes, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

For a simpler scenario without effective incoming rate, suppose there is a queue where customers arrive at rate $\lambda$ and they go into either of two lines with equal probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$. There is one server who serves the customer at rate $\lambda$. Regardless of the number of different lines, the one server can only serve one customer at a time so the exit rate is still $\lambda$.

If I am reading the question correctly, your outgoing rate is correct because $\lambda_1(1-P_k)+\lambda_2(1-P_k)=(1-P_k)(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)=\lambda(1-P_k)=\lambda_e$

Comment: Thanks, outgoing rate is correct, but what about the drop ratio? As An Example, if mean rate for flow1 is 10 jobs/second, and for flow 2 its 20 jobs/second, so combined incoming rate is 30 jobs/s, and lets say the drop probability is 20%, so for 30 packets, 6 will be dropped. Question is, Can I assume that, in long run, 2 job/s will be dropped from 1st flow and 4 jobs/s will be dropped from the second flow? or the drop values might be different?